# DNA from sweat on the hat band?

Tags: dna

My father died in 1987.  I have an old cowboy hat of his.  Can I use a [FamilyTreeDNA test kit](https://learn.familytreedna.com/testing-process/dna-test-kit-instructions/) to recover any DNA?

Comment: Related: [Does sweat contain DNA information?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/)